# how can I update a dynamodb model

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, model, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to update my dynamodb item in laravel using

https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb

this is my model; using php artisan tinker;

the attribute that I want to update is of 'map' type.

```
App\DynamoConfiguration {#1873
    op_city_id: 1,
    created_at: "2018-10-08T11:02:42+00:00",
    updated_at: "2018-10-08T11:11:26+00:00",
    info: [
        "shopper_logs_enabled" => "1",
    ],
}
```

when I do this. the model is not updated

```
$dynamo_configuration = DynamoConfiguration::where('op_city_id', 1)->first();
$info = $dynamo_configuration->info;
$info['shopper_logs_enabled'] = '0';
$dynamo_configuration->update(["info" => $info]);
return $dynamo_configuration;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the map attribute in the Eloquent Object and then save it to DynamoDB.

```
$dynamo_configuration = DynamoConfiguration::where('op_city_id', 1)->first();
$info = $dynamo_configuration->info;
$info['shopper_logs_enabled'] = '0';
$dynamo_configuration->info = $info;
$dynamo_configuration->save();
return $dynamo_configuration;
```

Edit: Fixed the code

Comment: getting error `Indirect modification of overloaded property App\DynamoConfiguration::$info has no effect`

Comment: I've updated my code example. check if this is working

Answer (score 0):

You can use updateAsync, update will not take effect immediately

```
// update asynchronously and wait on the promise for completion.
$model->updateAsync($attributes)->wait();
```